# Expectation number of 2-chains (consequent subsets, description is post)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, permutations

Given a set of numbers $\{ 1, 2, 3, ..., n \}$. Also given a set of subsets: $\{M_1, ..., M_s\}$ - such subsets that $|M_i| = k$ and $ \forall i,j \implies|M_i \cap M_j| = 1$.

We make a random permutation of elements of set $\sigma$.

Let's define **2-chain** -- it is two subsets, $M_i, M_j$ with one common element - $x$ and for every element $y \in M_i$ true that $\sigma(y) < \sigma(x)$, and and for every element $z \in M_j$ true that $\sigma(z) > \sigma(x)$. It's increasing **2-chain** and in the same way we could define decreasing **2-chain**

And the question: what is expected number of **2-chains** would be among ${M_1, ..., M_s}$?

My idea: firstly we should choose $\sigma(x)$, if it will be too close to borders, than we can't construct such **2-chains**. It gives $2(k - 1)$ forbidden places.

If $k \leq \sigma(x) \leq n - k$ find number of two sets that would be **2-chains**. $C_{\sigma(x) - 1}^{k - 1}$ - how we can choose elements for $M_i$ and $C_{n - \sigma(x)}^{k - 1}$ - how we can choose elements for $M_j$

$$ 2 (n - 2k + 1)! \sum\limits_{\sigma(x) = k}^{n - k} C_{\sigma(x) - 1}^{k - 1} C_{n - \sigma(x)}^{k - 1}$$

Than the probability that two subsets is **2-chain** is(obviously, not work for $k = 1$):

$$P =  \frac{2 (n - 2k + 1)!}{n!} \sum\limits_{\sigma(x) = k}^{n - k} C_{\sigma(x) - 1}^{k - 1} C_{n - \sigma(x)}^{k - 1} $$

This sum is easly obtain:

$$P = 2 \frac{((k - 1)!)^2}{(2k - 1)!}$$

And excpected number of **2-chains** in $\{M_1, ..., M_s\}$ is easly:

$$E = \frac{((k - 1)!)^2}{(2k - 1)!} s (s - 1)$$

Is it correct?

It's also second qustion, I don't know should I create another topic on it:
Proof that if exist such permutation $\sigma$ that there is no **2-chains**, than we can coloured all elements $\{ 1, 2, 3, ..., n \}$ in two colours(red and blue, for example), that all subsets $M_i$ would be bicolored. At this question I don't have any ideas at all.

Comment: I think your expression for $E$ is off by a factor of $2$. If $n=3$ and $k=s=2$ shouldn't $E=1/3$?

Comment: Actually, yes, thanks!